# JavaScript table dynamic color change

Tags: jquery, css

I dynamically add columns to the table.
I want to change the color of the column at this time, but it does not work well.

```
 if(i % 2 == 1) {
    $('#mytable>tbody:last').append('<tr style="background-color: #D7F9FD" >');
} else {
    $('#mytable>tbody:last').append('<tr style="bgcolor: #D7F9FD" >');
}
```

Help me~!!

Comment: Please add your HTML code inorder to see whether your $('#mytable>tbody:last') is correct or not

Comment: Are you getting errors in your console. If so please put them in your question or description. It will give people a clue about what is going on with the javascript

Comment: to specify column use <td/> inside <tr/> instead of using only <tr/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code sample there is no column is being created, to add column dynamically inside row use the statement below:

```
$('#mytable tbody').append('<tr class="yourclassNameIfyouwant"><td>1st column</td><td>2nd column</td></tr>');
```

By using JQuery even and odd selector we can find the respective rows as below:

Syntax:

```
$("#mytable tr:even").css("background-color", "#ccc");
```

The above code will find the even rows in table and apply back ground color.

```
$("#mytable tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
```

The above code will find the odd rows in table and apply back ground color.

and to specify even column of a row:

```
$('mytable tr :nth-child(2n)').css('background-color', '#eee');
```

to specify odd column of a row:

```
$('mytable tr :nth-child(2n+1)').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Every thing can be done after preparing rows and columns of the table on the fly.